# API integration into wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, api, integration

Im working on a gaming website and i want to incorporate an api into the buddypress/wordpress wesbite.

https://github.com/viion/XIVPads-LodestoneAPI

The trouble im having it where to actually start... The examples they give, i modified it so when 2 fields are entered ($ff14 & $ff14world) it will do a search for it.

```
<?php 
require 'api-autoloader.php';
$api = new Viion\Lodestone\LodestoneAPI();
$ff14 = bp_get_member_profile_data( 'field=Character' );
$ff14world = bp_get_member_profile_data( 'field=World' );

// Search by: name + world
$character = $api->Search->Character($ff14, $ff14world);

// Basic data
echo $character->name;
echo $character->world;
//var_dump( $character->classjobs );

?>
```

I tested it by putting it in the header.php file of the child theme and it output the result i wanted in the header but it wasn't picked up anywhere else on the website when i entered say `echo $character->name;`

In the end i just want people to be able to enter their character name/world in the profile page and within a separate tab the data from the `$character` variable will show :)

Ive been searching and stuffing around for about a week now.... Do i put it in the header.php... maybe the themes function.php.... ive tried but haven't successfully done it. Any tips?

- Justin

Comment: You can explain this problem a little more. What i understood is, your script will work for logged in users. If yes, then work with a condition is_user_logged_in() and if you think that no need to wait for WordPress to render then you can avoid including it in header.php. Its better to hook where WordPress get initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the end i just want people to be able to enter their character
>   name/world in the profile page and within a separate tab the data from
>   the $character variable will show

A separate tab where?  On the member's profile page? 
[Adding a profile tab example](https://gist.github.com/shanebp/5d3d2f298727a0a036e5).
Putting your code in the theme header is very inefficient.

This function `bp_get_member_profile_data` is meant to be used when viewing a member's page.  It assumes that the member id is the displayed member - unless you pass it another id. To retrieve profile data 'outside' of a member page, use `function xprofile_get_field_data( $field, $user_id = 0, $multi_format = 'array' )`

This example will show the lodestone field values in the member-header file:     `buddypress\bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members\single\member-header.php`

This code can go in your theme/functions.php or in plugins/bp-custom.php

```
function justin_show_lodestone() {
     require 'api-autoloader.php';  // adjust path as necessary
     $api = new Viion\Lodestone\LodestoneAPI();
     $ff14 = bp_get_member_profile_data( 'field=Character' );
     $ff14world = bp_get_member_profile_data( 'field=World' );

     // Search by: name + world
     $character = $api->Search->Character($ff14, $ff14world);

     // Basic data
     echo $character->name;
     echo $character->world;

}
add_action('bp_profile_header_meta', 'justin_show_lodestone');
```